# Как обособить пояснение? Кажется, нужно тире

Tags: пунктуация, пояснение

***Большие кошки(,) (—) львы, гепарды и тигры(,) (—) в основном являются наземными животными.***

Или:

***Большие кошки(,) (—) львы, гепарды и тигры(,) (—) наземные животные***.

Во втором случае, если тире, то оно, получается, одновременно разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое и обособляет пояснение?

Мне кажется, лучше обособить тире. Во-первых, пояснение более сложное, во-вторых, оно как бы выделено паузой. А вы как считаете?

Comment: Во втором случае надо скобки.

Comment: Есть логическая ошибка. Получается, что к большим кошкам относятся только львы, гепарды и тигры, а это не так (ещё леопарды, барсы и ягуары). Можно добавить "например".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Решение**

1. *Большие кошки **(львы, гепарды и тигры)** — наземные животные.*

2.1.  *Большие кошки: **львы, гепарды и тигры** — являются наземными животными. Об отдельных видах больших кошек.*

2.2 *Большие кошки  — **львы, гепарды и тигры** — являются наземными животными.  О больших кошках в целом.*

**Пояснение**

*Большие кошки — львы, гепарды и тигры — наземные животные.*

Это **некорректное** оформление. Основная структура  (подлежащее и именное сказуемое)  и обособленный ряд  не определяется по этой записи. Также невозможно это сделать в устной речи с помощью интонации.

**[О больших кошках](https://1-4all.livejournal.com/306933.html)**

Крупные представители семейства кошачьих – это и есть большие кошки. Однако немногие знают, что главным критерием принадлежности к большим кошкам является **не размеры, а строение.**

Итак, к большим кошкам относятся **лев, тигр, ягуар, леопард, снежный барс и дымчатый леопард**, но как ни странно, к ним не относятся такие виды как **пума и гепард.**